# Adding an item to the bottom of a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

When the adapter is upgraded, the information is not displayed at the bottom

I do not know exactly where the problem is
I need guidance so I can find out about this subject
As I see in the code, I want to add the added data down to the bottom when the user clicks on the button.

```
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
                mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
                mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                adminchat.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                adNewFullChat = new AdNewFullChat(activity ,  totalRestaurants);
                adminchat.setAdapter(adNewFullChat);
                mLayoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(adminchat, null, totalRestaurants.size());



public void onClick(View view) {
                            String text = chattext.getText().toString();
                            if (text.length() > 0) {
                                final Chat chat = new Chat();
                                chat.setTag("admin");
                                chat.setTimestamp(format);
                                chat.setUserid(userid);
                          totalRestaurants.add(chat);
                                        adNewFullChat.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        if (adNewFullChat.getItemCount() > 1) {
                                            adminchat.getLayoutManager().smoothScrollToPosition(adminchat, null, adNewFullChat.getItemCount() - 1);
                                        }
```

Adapter codes :
I do not understand exactly where the work is

```
public AdNewFullChat(Context context, List<Chat> messageList) {
    mContext = context;
    mMessageList = messageList;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mMessageList.size();
}

// Determines the appropriate ViewType according to the sender of the message.
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Chat message = (Chat) mMessageList.get(position);

    if (message.getTag().equals("user")) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED;

    } else if (message.getTag().equals("admin")) {
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT;

    }
    return 0;
}

// Inflates the appropriate layout according to the ViewType.
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_message, parent, false);
        return new SentMessageHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.their_message, parent, false);
        return new ReceivedMessageHolder(view);
    }

    return null;
}



// Passes the message object to a ViewHolder so that the contents can be bound to UI.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Chat message = (Chat) mMessageList.get(position);

    switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_SENT:
            ((SentMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED:
            ((ReceivedMessageHolder) holder).bind(message);
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste the AdNewFullChat(I guess this is the adapter) code?

Comment: @leojg Adapter code ++ aded

Comment: I just saw that you use mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true); try removing that line

Comment: @leojg The problem has been solved, but I want to be a ReverseLayout RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding the code.

You need to update the `mMessageList` list on the adapter.

updating `totalRestaurants` won't modify the data in the adapter what you can do is having a method like this in your adapter:

`public void addElement(Chat chat) { mMessageList.add(chat) }`

And you call it like this:

```
adNewFullChat.addElement(chat);
```

instead of `totalRestaurants.add(chat);`

Edit: Ohh I didnt saw that you are using `mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);`

If you remove that line the new elements will be added to the bottom